# jquery file breaking visual light box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

im am having an issue with a jquery file making a visual light box video popup full screen instead of in a box on top of the page.

here is the site: http://gitastudents.com/~clarkb/group1/Students.html

on the homepage you can see ho the video is supposed to show up.

if i comment out this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>`
in the drop down menu head section the video works fine but the dropdowns dont.

what do i need to do to make the video and the dropdowns work properly together?

thanks in advance for the help!

bryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector is not working:

```
$("videogallery a[rel]")
```

And thus you get:

> $("#videogallery a[rel]").overlay is
>   not a function

in line 25 of videolightbox.js.

Which element did you want to match?

Comment: I now see that is the line that is breaking.  But I dont know what you mean by what element i want to match.  I guess I want to match what it is set to as it works fine in the home page.  what do i need to do so that the 2 files dont conflict?

Comment: It seems you are actually loading jQuery 1.3.2, not 1.4.4 and it might come from the jquery.tools.min.js file, although it is very hard to track due to the extreme amount of script files and script fragments.
Try getting a newer version of jquery tools to try and solve dependency problems that might break the drop downs.